# ClassCastException in hibernate with unknown source of HashMap

Tags: java, hibernate, classcastexception

I'm currently stuck on ClassCastException where I cant figure out whats happening exactly.

***NOTE*** the query itself has been altered for simplicity, as I believe the problem lies elsewhere.

Situation goes as follows: I want to retrieve a list of database entries in my service class with:

```
List<Object[]> queryList = dao.queryGenericArray("SELECT a, b FROM db");
```

In my understanding, the method queryGenericArray should return
a list of object arrays, as defined in the DAO class:

```
List<Object[]> result = q.list();
```

list() being defined by hibernate.

So now I have my queryList object array without any errors, so far so good. But when I try to access an array from the queryList, i get a ClassCastException stating:

**java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;**

My question now is, why and where is the list entry defined as HashMap ?

Thanks in advance, if I left out any vital information, please let me know.

[Stacktrace](http://pastebin.ca/4016222)

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace

Comment: What exactly is the content of the hashMap? What's the key?

Comment: I'm expecting an array of objects, objects being <String, Date>. Dont know what the content is, if I run .getClass() on a queryList entry, i get arrayList as type.

Comment: Put a debug point and see actually what you are getting..

Comment: Not sure how exactly to add a debug point, but I'll figure it out and respond when Ive succeeded.

Comment: Hashmap is something containing multiple key-value pairs. This method returns hashmap because the author of it want to. And it should be more efficiency here.

Comment: I've noticed that the "structure" of the passed object is the same as a HashMap, but hibernate returns an object array from the db and so does queryGenericArray from the DAO class. I agree that HashMap would be more efficient, so I'll try to reconfigue the DAO class to return a HashMap to the service class. Thanks for the tips so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out, thanks to the comments on my inital question.

Problem was, I oversaw (or neglected) one line of code in the DAO class (I am not the author of this class):

```
q.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
```

This line, transforms the `object[]` to a map, as pretty concisely stated.

What I further had to do, was for one change the return type of my queryGenericArray  method from `object[]` to `List<HashMap<String, Date>>` and secondly cast the result of the hibernate method like this:

`List<HashMap<String, Date>> result = q.list();`

Now I can correctly access the data in the hashmaps contained in the passed list.